# TimePicker getHours(), getMinutes in API 15

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms, android-calendar, android-timepicker

I'm making a simple Alarm Clock app, to study `BroadcastReceivers` , the problem is `getHours() and getMinutes()` are only available for API 23.

- Is there any alternative way of achieving this?
- If so? Will it possible solution be applicable to higher API like 24?

Here's my sample code: `AlarmActivity.java`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    setWidgets();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceivers.class);

}

public void setWidgets(){
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    //Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    buttonSetAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSetAlarm);
    buttonSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int getHour = timePicker.getHour();
            int getMinute = timePicker.getMinute();

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getHour());
            calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());

            if (getHour > 12){
                int twelve = getHour - 12;
            }

            if (getMinute < 10){

            }

            setText("On");

        }
    });
```

I'm stuck with the `getHour()` and `getMinute()`.

Answer (score 14):

As `getHour()` and `getMinute()` are for API 23 and above, if your application targets lower APIs you need to add support for them.

You can do this by adding the following:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23){
    int getHour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
    int getMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
} else{
    int getHour = timePicker.getHour();
    int getMinute = timePicker.getMinute();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getMinute());
}
```

Both `getCurrentHour()` and `getCurrentMinute()` are deprecated but still work on lower APIs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the get() Methode from the Calendar class.

```
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```